# what's the right technique to redirect an Exception from a Servlet to a default error JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to have a default error JSP page which is shown when an exception is thrown by the servlet, and that page will show the stacktrace..

How do I do that?? is there a right technique (provided by the API) or I have to do it manually?? I mean, sending the exception thrown as an attribute and then dealing with it by myself??

Thanks

Comment: ...you must know that showing the stacktrace to a user constitutes a security risk.

Comment: thinking hardly about it, now I see you're right.. thanks for the advise..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the exception type and the JSP page to handle in web.xml, e.g:

```
<error-page>
       <exception-type>UnhandledException</exception-type>
       <location>UnhandledException.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

There's an Oracle article here on the subject:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/codesnippet/servlets/HandlingServletExceptions/HandlingServletExceptions.html

Comment: I've done that many times, but it doesn't work.
Going to read the link you provided.

Thank you.

Comment: The url refering to Oracle site has changed: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnaet/index.html